# Twilio MessagingResponse() after Flask redirect

Tags: python, flask, twilio

As in the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python#receive-and-reply-to-inbound-sms-messages-with-flask), I can make a MessagingResponse() object for sending a response text to my phone. However, what if I want to first redirect to an internal page? I am not able to simply make a MessagingResponse() in the redirected function, like I want to:

```
@app.route("/news", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def news():
    ....
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(msg)
    return ""

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    return redirect("news")
```

I am not getting a text back if I use the above code. However, if I manually create a Client from twilio.rest as follows:

```
@app.route("/news", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def news():
    ....
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    message = client.messages.create(to=request.values.get("From"), from_=request.values.get("To"),
                                         body=msg)
```

I successfully do what I want to do. I don't understand why MessagingResponse() doesn't work when the request object is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet is how you respond to incoming text messages with XML or TwiML (one thing)
`from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse`

while your second snippet is how you send text messages via REST API (another thing)
`from twilio.rest import Client`

Looking at your first snippet, if you're responding with an empty string to incoming text messages, you will not get a text back (Twilio will not do anything), as such:

instead of

```
return ""
```

try

```
return str(resp)
```

and make sure `msg` is not empty.